# Update panel, user Control and RegisterClientScriptInclude

Tags: asp.net

I have a Master page with a script manager. I have a content page with an update panel. Inside the update panel i have several User controls which initially are all visible=false. After Opening one of the User control, i have not been able to attach my js file using
RegisterClientScriptInclude. I have used:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, this.GetType(), "key5", ResolveClientUrl("~/js/configurator.js"));
```

on the master page, on the content page and in the user control code behind. none of which shows that the js file is being loaded. i have always been able to do this but all controls have been visible from begining.
Could someone point how to load the script so that it is available for the User Control?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is create a javascript handler like this so that it could be pick up after visible=true. $("button").live("click", function(e){......});